# How to show sidebar router page in Tab

Tags: reactjs, devextreme

I am using DevExtreme react template in my react js project from below link.The router page navigation is working fine as per my requirement.I would like to know how to use router page navigation as in "Tab" instead of single page.For example if we take from below link,there are two pages in sidebar (profile and display data pages).If I click "Profile and display page" ,both the pages should display in Tab but currently its shows only current page.hope its clear.

https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-react-template/#/home

Answer (score 0):

I also want to note that you can contact DevExpress support team directly at [Submit a Support Ticket](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/create). They answer questions in 24 hours, so you will be able to resolve the issue faster.